# Get image from File in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking

I tried to get image from downloaded files. Firstly i get images and download them.

```
-(void)saveMoodImage{

for (NSDictionary *dc in self.arrMood) {
    NSLog(@"dc: %@",dc);
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/images/%@",kRootUrl,dc[@"image"]];
    NSString* encodedUrl = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                            NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];



    [[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodImageUrl addObject:URL];
    [[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodName addObject:dc[@"text"]];


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]];
        return [documentsDirectoryPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
        [[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodImagePath addObject:filePath];


    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

}
Result logs:

```
2014-03-20 00:30:48.174 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-2389-4AF6-7328-ESD213AD343S/Documents/angry.png
2014-03-20 00:30:48.185 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-2389-4AF6-7328-ED0FAF04A97E/Documents/shine.png
2014-03-20 00:30:48.194 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-2389-4AF6-7328-ESD213AD343S/Documents/relaxed.png
2014-03-20 00:30:48.196 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-2389-4AF6-7328-ESD213AD343S/Documents/bored.png
2014-03-20 00:30:48.219 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-2389-4AF6-7328-ESD213AD343S/Documents/happy.png
2014-03-20 00:30:48.233 ImageTutorial[1124:60b] File downloaded to: file:///var/mobile/Applications/2HH213HGH-8322-4AF6-7328-ESD213AD343S/Documents/sick.png
```

Then i set the image to `UIImageView`

```
self.IV_test.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodImagePath[i]]]
```

Finally, i could not set the image. Have you any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new UIImageView and put it on the screen, or just change the image of a UIImageView that's already on the screen?

Comment: I changed code but it did not work again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're confusing an `ImageView` with an `UIImage`. You are assigning an instance of `UIImage` to a `UIImageView` variable.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodImagePath[i]]]
```

What you need to do is some how get an instance of the View you have on screen and assign the image to it. Something like

```
UIImageView *imgView = //... get instance from screen, alloc init, NIB, storyboard, ...
imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[MUtility sharedObject].arrMoodImagePath[i]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Break your final statement into parts. Extract the pathname to a string. Log it.

Load the image at that path into a UIImage in a local variable. Log that.

Then, install the image into the image view. If that doesn't work, check to see if your image view property is nil. (A broken outlet link is a common reason code doesn't work as expected)